# SSH failed while connect to PC without monotor

Tags: boot, server, openssh

I am trying to use my PC as online server.
Everything works perfect when the monitor, keyboard and mouse is connected.
I can remote ssh to my PC after boot even without login to Ubuntu with my user/pswd.

However, once I disconnect my monitor to my PC server and turn my PC on.
I can no longer ssh connect to my PC, and if I connect monitor to PC again, there's no signal sign jump out.

Comment: Is the machine suspending or hibernating when the monitor is disconnected? Some systems will do this as part of "power saving" measures. If so, you'll need to check your BIOS settings to make sure the computer can run "headless".

Comment: I'm not sure about the status of pc which I turn on without monitor connected,
my motherboard is Asus prime x370 pro, I'll check.